# IE11 Save As Popup handling issue WebDriver/Autoit/Robot

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, autoit, sikuli

I need to download and save .CSV file in IE11, When i try to click save as button in the Download popup,i Couldn't able to click it and not able to set focus on the popup, I have tried

1. Autoit
2. Robot
3. sendkeys(keys.TAB)
4. Sikuli

But it getting failed.

Comment: If you can use autoit (not autoitX dll), you could try [InetGet](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/InetGet.htm) which might be easier than automation of a browser.

Comment: There are some similar questions for IE download with AutoIt, please do a research. Otherwise provide your tryouts with AutoIt please.